# i want to install THREE.JS with npm. found 15 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, installation, three.js

#### i am doing the tutorial on the official documentation.

[image: the official documentation - three.js]

> I see, that I need to write this: `npm install three --save-dev`
> [image: code npm on official three.js]

---

i do it, i have a lot of **ERRORS**

- i have installed before `npm` so is not the problem of me not having npm.
- i see i do to `npm audit fix`, but is not that easy as i think [image: error WARN npm]

---

```
PS C:\Users\laaou\Desktop\three> npm install three --save-dev
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'C:\Users\laaou\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open     'C:\Users\laaou\package.json'
npm WARN tailwindcss@2.2.7 requires a peer of autoprefixer@^10.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN laaou No description
npm WARN laaou No repository field.
npm WARN laaou No README data      
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ three@0.132.2

18 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 15 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
PS C:\Users\laaou\Desktop\three> npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\laaou\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-31T17_59_47_376Z-debug.log
```

### [image: code terminal error]

## interesting part:

- the interesting part is... the folder is **empty**
  [image: empty folder]
- but the `git` icon has 5K [image: 5k icon git vscode error] changes, this is **not** normal... normally i do: 1 to 5 changes
- 5000 git changes, without any file in my folder. [image: A LOT OF FILES]

*EDIT: i think is vscode extension code and source code, because is Imposible the fact is 5k only for three.js.*

---

i dont know how i have this error (i am a beginner).

---

> thank if you help me, i will put ✅ if is useful.

---

Comment: three.js [does not have any production dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three), and this question seems to describe a lot of (possible) vulnerabilities in various dependencies, so I think something may be missing from the reproduction steps here. Aside, `npm audit` can be [notoriously noisy](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) with dev dependencies.

Comment: npm complaints (this is technically a warning, not an error) come from npm, not Git; Git isn't involved at all here. VS and some plugins may or may not be involved, if that's how you invoke npm, but Git isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project does not appear to be setup properly. It is setup for `git`, but not for `npm`.

The error message:

```
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json
```

is stating you must have a package.json file.

```
npm init -y
```

will get a basic npm structure

---

second thing is you are seeing git changes in vscode source control, but not seeing the files in explorer. This may be because your explorer is filtering those directories: `node_modules` and `.git`

Settings > Search for "files.exclude" > check the list

typically .git is hidden by default

Comment: thank you, yes `npm init -y` i see a json created, now `package.json` and now i see `package-lock.json` is it normal this lock?

Comment: @laaouatni it is normal and you should include it in your git repository.